# How bad is the trapezoid rule in the approximation of $ n! = \int_0^\infty x^n \, e^{-x} \, dx $?

Tags: numerical-methods, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (over $\mathbb{R}$) allows us to express the factorial function as an [Euler integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_integral):
$$ n! = \int_0^\infty x^n \, e^{-x} \, dx $$
What happens if we use the [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) on the improper integral on the right hand side?  For general functions it says:
$$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \approx (b-a) \left[ \frac{f(a)+ f(b)}{2} \right] $$
We can partition $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $  as the union of segments $[n,n+1]$ for over all possible integers $n \geq 0$.  Therefore:
$$ a! \approx \sum_{m \geq 0} 1 \cdot \frac{m^a \, e^{-m}+ m^{a+1}e^{-(m+1)}}{2} =  - \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{m \geq 0} m^a e^{-m}$$

How bad is the trapezoid rule in this kind of estimate?  The error term is usually:

$$ \left|\; \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \;- \;(b-a) \left[ \frac{f(a)+ f(b)}{2} \right] \; \right| \leq \frac{(b-a)^3}{12}f''(\xi) $$

So for each term we are losing $\frac{1}{12} \times \text{constant}$.  Can we understand this error term better?

---

Related: [An Elementary Proof of Error Estimates for the Trapezoidal Rule](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3219088) D. Cruz-Uribe and C. J. Neugebauer

Comment: $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^+}\left|\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^n e^{-x}\right|$$ can be computed in a explicit way, this is not a difficult problem. But such $\sup$ is rather large, so the trapezoid method is not a great idea for deriving accurate numerical approximations of $\Gamma(n+1)$.

Comment: I would use one of the standard transforms to map the interval to ]0, 1[. Then the Fourier coefficients will tell you how fast the trapezoidal quadrature converges: http://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/trap-iap-2011.pdf